# Vanilla JS remove eventlistener in currying function

Tags: javascript, currying

I have a very "simple" vanillaJS problem. How can I remove event listener in loop inside a currying function? This just an example of my current solution where I actually need multiple parameters coming to the listener. I suspect that the event listener is not removed due to anonymous callback if I am right? How can I fix this? Example here https://codepen.io/shnigi/pen/wvPwqVR

```js
const setEventListener = (buttons) => (event) => {
  const buttonValue = event.target.value;
  console.log('Eventlistener exists', buttonValue)
  buttons.forEach(button => button.removeEventListener('click', setEventListener));
};

const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');
buttons.forEach(button => button.addEventListener('click', setEventListener(buttons)));

// Works as expected, listener is named
const testbutton = document.getElementById('kek');
const testListener = () => {
  console.log('I show up only once');
  testbutton.removeEventListener('click', testListener);
};

testbutton.addEventListener('click', testListener);
```

```html
<button value="1">press me</button>
<button value="2">press me</button>
<button id="kek">eventlistener removed on click</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I suspect that the event listener is not removed due to anonymous callback if I am right?

Yes, that is a problem.
So you have to assigned anonymous function to variable and use it to remove event listener.

Here is sample code for you.

```js
const setEventListener = (buttons: NodeList) => {
    const returnedFunc = (event: Event) => {
      const buttonValue = (event.target as HTMLButtonElement).value;
      console.log('Eventlistener exists', buttonValue)
      buttons.forEach(button => button.removeEventListener('click', returnedFunc));
    };
    return returnedFunc;
};

const buttons: Nodelist = document.querySelectorAll('button');
buttons.forEach(button => button.addEventListener('click', setEventListener(buttons)));

// Works as expected, listener is named
const testbutton = document.getElementById('kek');
const testListener = () => {
  console.log('I show up only once');
  testbutton.removeEventListener('click', testListener);
};

testbutton.addEventListener('click', testListener);
```

Comment: Thanks! I knew what was wrong but somehow couldn't get my head around it. So the actual "listener" is the returned function which I want to remove.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about Internet Explorer support, you can remove anonymous event listeners in more elegant way using [AbortController](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortController). Pass `signal` option to `addEventListener()` and call AbortController's `abort()` method when you want to remove event listener:

```
var listenersRemover = new AbortController();
button.addEventListener('click', callback, {signal: listenersRemover.signal}));
listenersRemover.abort();
```

`Note`: you should "rearm" abort controller to use the same signal for the new `addEventListener()` calls. Just initialize it again with `new AbortController()`.

```js
var listenersRemover = new AbortController();

const setEventListener = (buttons) => (event) => {
  const buttonValue = event.target.value;
  console.log('Eventlistener exists', buttonValue)
  // buttons.forEach(button => button.removeEventListener('click', setEventListener));
};

const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');
buttons.forEach(button => button.addEventListener('click', setEventListener(buttons), {signal: listenersRemover.signal}));

// Works as expected, listener is named
const testbutton = document.getElementById('kek');
const testListener = () => {
  console.log('I show up only once');
  //testbutton.removeEventListener('click', testListener);
  listenersRemover.abort();
};

testbutton.addEventListener('click', testListener, {signal: listenersRemover.signal});
```

```html
<button value="1">press me</button>
<button value="2">press me</button>
<button id="kek">eventlistener removed on click</button>
```

Comment: You forgot to add listenersRemover.abort(); in the setEventListener function, but I got it. This is good to know! Didn't know about this method at all.

Comment: @Shnigi, in this case the setEventListener function will remove all event listeners after the first click.